# Advise on best way to regress this and how to apply the method (probably panel data)

Tags: regression, time-series, econometrics, panel-data, eviews

Till now I have had two econometrics courses, so my knowledge is limited up to censored/truncated etc.
Now I did not have time series analysis yet, but after speaking to the professor of the course he thinks it is best to apply panel data method.

So the data that I am concerned with is basically from 25 countries over like period of 3-5 years. The dependent variable is censored in that it has a lower limit of 0 and an upper limit of 10. Now, this index will be regressed on a variety of independent variables, like population size, a dummy, amount invested by government and a number representing economies of scale.
The thing I am after is if the effect of economies of scale is significant and if so is positive or negative on the performance measured by the dependent index.

Thus with the data of the 25 countries over a period of 3-5 years, I want to know the effect of economies of scale. How to best tackle this problem and which method to use? If possible, could you give me a step method on how to apply it in practice (preferably with eviews).

PS this is not a homework assignment, so I am not trying to get an easy answer.

Comment: A [tag:mixed-mode] (aka hierarchical model aka [tag:multilevel-analysis] with years nested in countries may do the job